# How to add Case as an option in the "Related To" drop down of emails in SFDC?

Tags: email, case

Users send emails from Cases often and found that when they click on an email address anywhere in SFDC, the email editor pops open and they can relate it to any record/object except for Case for some reason. I'm not sure where this setting is, if there is one to designate what objects are available to related to the email. Does anyone know how to get Case available?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 fields on the EmailMessage object which links the email to other objects

```
ParentId : This field relates to only ***Cases***

RelatedToId : This field related to objects other than cases
```

**Docked Email Composer** feature came out in Winter 20, which allows us to write emails in the composer, but seems like the composer doesn't have "parentId" field on it. This is a potential Idea.

Release notes : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_cases_popout_to_docked_email_composer.htm&type=5&release=222

EmailMessage doc : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm

Answer (score 0):

As per [Send Email Action Considerations for Cases](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.case_interaction_send_email_quick_action_considerations.htm&type=5):

> The Related To field can’t be set to Cases in the global Send Email action.